# Authentication problem - and I still can't change the password

Tags: password, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost Administrative(root) password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password)

My question has been previously asked by other users, but has been dismissed by those who answered. I changed the password to blank, but ubuntu still keeps on asking me for authentication every time I open a program and both blank and my old password do not work. I am certain I do remember my old password. I tried changing it in grub but when I go to the console in root and type passwd [my account name] then asks me to type and retype my new password the console does not react to my typing. When I still type my password, assuming it simply just does not show it but it receives it I get an error: token malfunction, password unchanged. Please help, I need my computer for work.

Comment: You cannot use blank passwords for administrative accounts, you need to reset your password now else you are locked in your system.

Comment: Use the guide on the link above to reset your password.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the password to blank. Delete it. Do the following as root user.

```
passwd -d
```

From the manual

> ```
>    -d, --delete
>        Delete a users password (make it empty). This is a quick way to
>        disable a password for an account. It will set the named account
>        passwordless.
> ```